# Internationalization of number abbreviations/truncation

Tags: ios, objective-c, internationalization, number-formatting

I have a section of code that abbreviates large numbers to shorter forms, truncating the less significant digits.

Example:

```
3732 -> 3.7k
432761 -> 432k
3786532 -> 3.8m
```

However, now I am looking to find a way of doing the same thing in non-English-speaking locales, where the character used to denote thousand and million might be different, and billion might refer to a different number entirely (long scale). Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Use `NSByteCountFormatter`.

Comment: @rmaddy I was looking for something _like_ that but I don't think that will solve my issue. I haven't found any flag that causes it to count in arbitrary units ('k' for thousand vs KB), and I don't know how to convert it in a locale independent manner.